# ant claims Implementation-Title/Version/Vendor not set, but they are

Tags: ant

I'm running ant 1.8.0 in verbose mode. I have created a manifest containing Implementation-Title, -Version and -Vendor and the resulting JAR contains a manifest with those in it. The JAR's class runs fine. However, output from ant says

> [jar] No Implementation-Title set.No Implementation-Version set.No Implementation-Vendor set.

Is this just a bug in ant or am I missing something here?

Thanks

Here's my ant code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="helloworld.makejar" default="makejar" basedir=".">
  <target name ="makejar" description="Create a JAR for the HelloWorld project">
    <delete file="helloworld.jar" />
    <delete file="MANIFEST.MF" />

    <manifest file="MANIFEST.MF">
      <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
      <attribute name="Main-Class" value="project.builder.example.HelloWorld" />
      <section name="common">
        <attribute name="Specification-Title"    value="Example" />
        <attribute name="Specification-Version"  value="1.0.0" />
        <attribute name="Specification-Vendor"   value="Example Organization" />
        <attribute name="Implementation-Title"   value="common" />
        <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0.0 today" />
        <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor"  value="Acme Corp." />
      </section>
    </manifest>

    <jar jarfile="helloworld.jar"
         includes="**/*.class"
         basedir="bin"
         manifest="MANIFEST.MF"
     />
  </target>
  <javac srcdir="src" destdir="bin" />
</project>
```

Comment: How are you creating the manifest? Did you create it by hand or are you using the manifest nested element of Ant's jar task? Can you post the contents of the manifest file?

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. I added my ant code so you can see how the manifest is created and consumed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is that the attributes must be defined as children of the manifest element, as opposed to being children of the nested section.

**Update**

Maybe using an inline manifest element would make a difference. The following snippet is from the Ant docs:

```
<jar destfile="test.jar" basedir=".">
    <include name="build"/>
    <manifest>
        <!-- Who is building this jar? -->
        <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}"/>
        <!-- Information about the program itself -->
        <attribute name="Implementation-Vendor" value="ACME inc."/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="GreatProduct"/>
        <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="1.0.0beta2"/>
        <!-- details -->
        <section name="common/MyClass.class">
            <attribute name="Sealed" value="false"/>
        </section>
    </manifest>
</jar>
```

Comment: Removing the section hierarchy did not fix the problem. Moreover, I observe that this does not go amiss from the command line. Perhaps this is a peculiarity of Eclipse running ant?

Comment: Another thing that might make a difference is using an inline manifest element in the jar task instead of a separate manifest element. Answer updated above.